# Перенос сайта wordpress с локалки . Не переписывает пути ссылок

Tags: wordpress, ссылки

Проблема в следующем. Сделал сайт на локальном хостинге на вордпресс. Сделал шаблоны для разного типа страниц,в т.ч. и для главной. Переношу сайт на хотсинг с помощью плагина duplicator. Дальше заменяю ссылки с помощью better-search replace. В итоге url меняются нормально, страницы сайта открываются, но вот ссылки в шаблонах остались локальными и не работают. Выгрузил базу данных, думал может что-то не заменилось, но этих ссылок там нет. Выходит код в шаблонах никак не связан с базой данных и менять вручную? Стоит ли? Или этого быть не должно и этой мой косяк? Подскажите , умаялся уже.

Comment: Обратитесь к фрилансеру, специалисту по вп.

Answer (score 0):

> Переношу сайт на хотсинг с помощью плагина duplicator. Дальше заменяю ссылки с помощью better-search replace

BSR не нужен - дубликаор сам всё поменяет.

> но вот ссылки в шаблонах остались локальными и не работают.

В шаблонах вообще не должно быть никаких ссылок. В см долины быть относительно корня сайты или темы темы.

Comment: А насколько критично наличие абсолютных ссылок?

Answer (score 0):

Для переезда нужно использовать только архив, сделанный плагином duplicator. После копирование архива на новый хостинг запускается инсталятор duplicator, где на 2-3 шаге указываете новые данные для подключения.
В шаблонах лучше указывать ссылки в кратком виде, тогда будет проще переносить сайт

```
<ul>    
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(1); ?>">О блоге</a></li>    
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(10); ?>">Об авторе</a></li>    
</ul>
```

"Выходит код в шаблонах никак не связан с базой данных и менять вручную?" - конечно, БД это одно, а файлы темы - это сам шаблон, совсем другое.

Comment: Или напишите в скайп.